# How to handle html tags in highlight fragment in SOLR

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene

I use SOLR hit highlighting feature to set highlights in a document matches the query.

The problem is one of the fields contain valid HTML, but highlight fragment returned is not valid HTML, that's why after the rendering whole page layout is broken.

For example query `field:lucene` get me this document:

`<p><a href="/some/link">Here is the discussion, what the difference between SOLR, Elasticsearch and Lucene</a></p>`

Highlight fragment is `Elasticsearch and <em>Lucene</em></a></p>`.

One of the option I've tried to set fragment size = 0 (return whole field content) but it can be very large and I need just a few snippets for the result page.

Another option is to remove all HTML tags and show snippet in plain text, but I need `<em>` tags for highlighting. Also some tags could be broken in fragment like a `</p` that means we can't use html parsers for that purpose.

It seems like a common problem in search, is there some state-of-the-art approach to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution is to strip HTML on the way in (for example [using the HTMLCharFilter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory)), before indexing. That way you'll have a plain text field that you can do highlighting on, and display the result with the embedded `<em>` tags.

You can then use `copyField` to have a field with the HTML representation intact, and one without the HTML contained (to use for highlighting).