# How to highlight a query term in a field containing html in Solr

Tags: solr

I have a body field that may contain html text from a rich text editor. I want to be able to return highlighted snippets from it, but with the html stripped out.

Take the text below that gets indexed:

`<p class="something">some text here with words and other text</p>`

If you search for 'words', you might get the following highlight snippet (depending on fragment length etc):

`class="something">some text here with <em>words</em> and other text</p>`
or
`class="something">some text here with <em>words</em> and other text`

Where the HTML is split, which will cause rendering problems on the front-end. I want to strip out the html before the highlighting is applied. I've tried different highlighting components but haven't seen any properties that do the trick.

**Do I need to strip the HTML before indexing?** Or is there another technique for this?

At the moment I'm using HTMLStripCharFilterFactory to strip out HTML at index time, but the highlighting component using the underlying stored data which is the original html.

Comment: For anyone who comes across the same problem...I ended up stripping html before it comes into Solr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have the same problem and have concluded that the only way is to use two fields, for example:

1. content_html: original html, uses HtmlStripCharFilterFactory so just the html content will be indexed/tokenized
2. content_stripped: text content only, will be used for highlighted fragments

In C# I'd use HtmlAgilityPack, for example, to load the HTML into a document then call .Text on the root node.

Both fields should be stored so that you can use the text-only field for fragments and the html field for when you want the entire field to be highlighted.

I looked into both Solr and ElasticSearch and from what I found there's no built-in way because highlighting is performed on whatever is stored.

Related: [Solr Strip html when highlighting with stored html fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527374/solr-strip-html-when-highlighting-with-stored-html-fields?rq=1)

Related: [How to handle html tags in highlight fragment in SOLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25743671/how-to-handle-html-tags-in-highlight-fragment-in-solr?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer - have marked it as such for anyone else who comes across this.

Comment: pholly and @IanRoutledge -- can you confirm that even an analyzer which users `"char_filter" : ["html_strip"]` wouldn **not** help here, because analyzers only affect how content is **analyzed (tokenized, etc)** (and/or how queries are **analyzed**); analyzers do **not** affect how it's **stored**, and since the **stored** value is what matters for highlight-fragments, analyzers can't fix this highlight-fragments issue?