# How to get the surrounding html tag of a search hit with highlighting in Solr?

Tags: solr

We have HTML documents in Solr, where the body has the form:

```
<div>
...
    <p attrs="..">Some paragraph of arbitrary length, can be very long</p> <p moreAttrs="..">Another one</p>
...
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is to retrieve the surrounding tag for a search hit by using the highlighting feature of Solr.

I have been playing around with different `hl.xxx` settings including `hl.method` to test different highlighters with their respective settings, but not yet found anything that works.

For example, if I search for "of arbitrary", then `<p attrs="..">Some paragraph of arbitrary length, can be very long</p>` should be returned (and nothing else, meaning that setting a large `hl.fragsize`is not what I want to do if I can avoid that).

Comment: try by increasing the hl.fragsize

Comment: The paragraphs have an arbitrary length, which makes it very hard to set a good value I have found. And I always get more than I want, I just want the paragraph, nothing from before or after.

Comment: You would need to implement custom highlighter for this to take into account html tags

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to highlight a query term in a field containing html in Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323157/how-to-highlight-a-query-term-in-a-field-containing-html-in-solr)

Comment: The linked question does not match my problem, so I do not think it is a duplicate of that one